# BIG WEIRD ANSWER in a MATRIX multiplication program

Tags: multiplication

this is a program to multiply 2 matrixes which comes in maths, but dont know why, am getting answers like "-1282230" or some weird numbers. I would like to know what is causing it and how could i fix it? THANK YOU!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()

{

int m[3][3],m2[3][3],i,je,k,ans[3][3],sum;
```

// taking inputs from the user for matrix1

printf("Enter the numbers for first matrix");

```
je=0;

for(i=0;i<3;i++){

        printf(" for row %d\n",i+1);

    for(je=0;je<3;je++){

          scanf("%d",&m[i][je]);
    }

}

// taking inputs from the user for matrix2    

printf("Enter the numbers for second matrix");

je=0;

for(i=0;i<3;i++){

    printf(" for row = %d\n",i+1);

for(je=0;je<3;je++){

          scanf("%d",&m2[i][je]);
    }


}

// multiplication OR MATRIX CMS HERE;

sum = 0;

for(k=0;k<9;k++){

for(i=0;i<3;i++){

for(je=0;je<3;je++){


        sum =  m[k][je] * m2[je][i];

        ans[i][je] = sum;
    }

}

k++;

}

// it ENDS;

puts("ANSWER IS:: \n");

// Displaying answer, matrix; 

for(i=0;i<3;i++){

    for(je=0;je<3;je++){

        printf("%d\t",ans[i][je]);

    }

    printf("\n");

}


return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working solution. One of the problem with your code is that you aren't setting the sum to 0 after each multiplication.

```
#include <stdio.h>   

int main() {   
    int m, n, p, q, c, d, k, sum = 0;   int first[10][10], second[10][10], multiply[10][10];

    printf("Enter number of rows and columns of first matrix\n");   scanf("%d%d", &m, &n);   printf("Enter elements of first matrix\n");
    for (c = 0; c < m; c++)
    for (d = 0; d < n; d++)
      scanf("%d", &first[c][d]);
    printf("Enter number of rows and columns of second matrix\n");   scanf("%d%d", &p, &q);
    if (n != p)
    printf("The matrices can't be multiplied with each other.\n");   else   {
    printf("Enter elements of second matrix\n");

    for (c = 0; c < p; c++)
      for (d = 0; d < q; d++)
        scanf("%d", &second[c][d]);

    for (c = 0; c < m; c++) {
      for (d = 0; d < q; d++) {
        for (k = 0; k < p; k++) {
          sum = sum + first[c][k]*second[k][d];
        }

        multiply[c][d] = sum;
        sum = 0;
      }
    }

    printf("Product of the matrices:\n");

    for (c = 0; c < m; c++) {
      for (d = 0; d < q; d++)
         printf("%d\t", multiply[c][d]);
         printf("\n");
        }   
    }
    return 0; }
```